# Regex in Javascript to catch mentions

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I write a regex in javascript that matches all twitter like mentions (@something), but not email addresses.

I need to capture an unlimited number of mentions in a huge text field. Strings that have a non-printable characters and parentheses preceding the "@", should be captured.

Comment: Wouldn't it be something like `^@[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`? And I don't know what other characters are allowed, but just add them in between the brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/(?<!\w)@\w+/g
```

would be a simple solution, but since JavaScript does not support [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) it becomes a non-trivial task:

```
var matches = str.match(/(^|\W)@\w+/g);
for (var i=0; i<matches.length; i++)
    matches[i] = matches[i].replace(/^[^@]/, "");
```

If you want to support a wider range of characters (as from your edit), you would use

```js
/(?<![^\s(]@\S+/g // or respectively
/(^|[\s(])@\S+/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex

```
/(\s|^)@[^\s]+/
```

`\s` represents space..

Comment: Too bad JavaScript regex doesn't have lookbehind assertions. Depending on your needs, add punctuation inside the parentheses, like `(\s|\(|^)`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick JSFiddle to answer you:

```
var re = /\s@[\w\-]/
```

[Or just Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vtwdy/1/)

Note that you can see the results of the regex in the console (Firebug, for example).

Comment: Ok, but how do I capture all mentions at once?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
/\B@\w+/g
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/aMdDD7/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
 - \B - assert position where \b does not match
 - @ - matches the character @ with index 6410 (4016 or 1008) literally (case sensitive)
 - \w+ - matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]) between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Code demo:

```js
const str = `@something, but not email@addresses.com, @something2, but not email_12345@addresses.com`
console.log(str.match(/\B@\w+/g))
```

Comment: This solution is a better equivalent of `/(?<!\w)@\w+/` (see [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14323044/3832970)) because it is not using a lookbehind (not supported in Safari or some other environments). Note that `\B@` matches a `@` that is either at the start of the string or right after a non-word char, i.e. `\B@` = `(?<!\w)@`.